# Python requests library pre_request hook

Tags: python, python-requests

I'm having an issue with trying to switch from an ancient version of python-requests (0.14) to a newer version (1.1, 1.2 whatever). The problem is that we have a system which posts images on twitter using the following library: https://github.com/maraujop/requests-oauth

The main problem is with this line of code:

```
# This is taken from the documentation of the library mentioned above
session = requests.session(hooks={'pre_request': oauth_hook})
session.post(...)
```

As the Session constructor no longer accepts the hooks parameter. I found that the post method accept the hooks argument though and chagned the code like this:

```
session = requests.session()
session.post(..., hooks={'pre_request': oauth_hook})
```

This is better than before, however the pre_request is no longer accepted in newer version of python-requests (you can find this hook in the documentation of requests 0.14 but not in any of the newer versions). Can somebody help on this?

Comment: I believe as of 1.0 they've removed most 'hooks', but I'm not sure any more than that. Brief mention of the removal in the 1.0 version history https://pypi.python.org/pypi/requests

Comment: You might also consider using something that is supported, like: https://github.com/requests/requests-oauthlib

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to create the request object yourself, pass that to the hook, then call `.prepare()` on it:

```
import requests

request = requests.Request('POST', url, ...)
request = oauth_hook(request)
prepared = request.prepare()
```

then send:

```
session = requests.session()
resp = session.send(prepared)
```